# .vimrc configuration for Python

Tags: python, vim

My current .vimrc configuration is below:

```
set nohlsearch
set ai
set bg=dark
set showmatch
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=DarkGray
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set list
autocmd BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
syntax on
set listchars=tab:>-
set listchars+=trail:.
set ignorecase
set smartcase
map <C-t><up> :tabr<cr>
map <C-t><down> :tabl<cr>
map <C-t><left> :tabp<cr>
map <C-t><right> :tabn<cr>
```

However, when I write python scripts, when I push "ENTER", it will go to the BEGINNING of the next line. What do I add so that it will auto-tab for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is that your autocmd is missing the BufEnter trigger, so it isn't being fired when you create a new file. Try this instead:

```
 au BufEnter,BufRead *.py setlocal smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
```

Note that I also changed the `set` to `setlocal`. This'll prevent these options from stomping on your other buffers' options.

The "right" way to do what you're trying to do is to add `filetype indent on` to your .vimrc. This'll turn on the built-in filetype based indentation. Vim comes with Python indentation support. See `:help filetype-indent-on` for more info.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

I primarily do Python programming and this is the brunt of my vimrc

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set lines=40
set columns=80
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set smarttab
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using it. Though I also added `set expandtab`.

Answer (score 7):

Consider having a look at the official .vimrc for following PEP 7 & 8 conventions. Present over here

http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/Vim/vimrc

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to explicitly indent python keywords. The $VIM/indent/python.vim file takes care of that. You just need to turn on filetype indent and autoindent.

Answer (score 4):

I (simply) use this:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
syntax on
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this configuration provides something, without causing conflicts (`/etc/vim/vimrc`):

```
" Python Setup
autocmd Filetype python setlocal ts=2 sw=2 expandtab
autocmd Filetype python set number
autocmd Filetype python set autoindent
autocmd Filetype python set expandtab
autocmd Filetype python set shiftwidth=4
autocmd Filetype python set cursorline
autocmd Filetype python set showmatch
autocmd Filetype python let python_highlight_all = 1
autocmd Filetype python set colorcolumn=80
```