# Autoindenting with vim for python else statement

Tags: python, vim

In [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), I want to write the following code:

```
def a():
    if a: pass
    elif b: pass
    else: pass
```

I use autoindenting, but the code will be indented as:

```
def a():
    if a: pass
    elif b: pass
else: pass
```

The automatic indenting of the `else` statement is wrong. How can I fix this?

Note that the following code snippet gets indented correctly:

```
def a():
    if a: pass
    else: pass
```

Here's my complete `.vimrc`:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Sets how many lines of history VIM has to remember
set history=700

" Enable filetype plugins
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread

" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
" like <leader>w saves the current file
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

inoremap jj <ESC>
noremap <leader>q :qa<cr>

""" Bash shortcut
set shell=bash\ --rcfile\ ~/.vimbashrc
noremap <leader>bh :shell<cr>

noremap <leader><cr> @:
nmap <leader>bc <Plug>Kwbd
""" Replace grep command with user function smartgrep as old grep doesn't support --exclude-dir option
noremap <leader>gr :!bash -c ". ~/.alias; smartgrep "
"noremap <leader>gr :!grep -ir --color --exclude="*\.svn/*" --exclude="*obj/"
noremap <leader>nt :NERDTreeToggle<cr>

""" Open the python interpreter
noremap <leader>py :!python<cr>

""" Check for differences between file in buffer and on disk
command Wdiff :w !diff -u % -

let g:yankring_history_dir='$HOME/.vim/temp'
let MRU_File=expand('$HOME/.vim/temp/mru.txt')

set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
" modelines have historically been a source of security/resource
" vulnerabilities -- disable by default, even when 'nocompatible' is set
set nomodeline

" Set this, so the background color will not change inside tmux (http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html)
set t_ut=

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => VIM user interface
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Set 12 lines to the cursor - when moving vertically using j/k
set so=8

" Turn on the WiLd menu
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest

" Suffixes that get lower priority when doing tab completion for filenames.
" These are files we are not likely to want to edit or read.
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc

" Ignore compiled files
set wildignore=*.o,*~,*.pyc
if has("win16") || has("win32")
    set wildignore+=*/.git/*,*/.hg/*,*/.svn/*,*/.DS_Store
else
    set wildignore+=.git\*,.hg\*,.svn\*
endif

"Always show current position
set ruler

" Height of the command bar
set cmdheight=2

" A buffer becomes hidden when it is abandoned
set hid

" Configure backspace so it acts as it should act
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l

" Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase

" When searching try to be smart about cases 
set smartcase

" Highlight search results
set hlsearch

" Makes search act like search in modern browsers
set incsearch 

" Don't redraw while executing macros (good performance config)
set lazyredraw 

" For regular expressions turn magic on
set magic

" Show matching brackets when text indicator is over them
set showmatch 
" How many tenths of a second to blink when matching brackets
set mat=2

" No annoying sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set vb t_vb=
set tm=500

" Add a bit extra margin to the left
set foldcolumn=1


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Colors and Fonts
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax enable 

""" Use peaksea as graphical highlighting
""" When activating 256 colors, no bold fonts are shown
set t_Co=256 

" feel free to choose :set background=light for a different style 
set background=dark 
colors peaksea

""" Show line numbers
set number

""" Use mouse for all (a)
set mouse=a

" Set utf8 as standard encoding and en_US as the standard language
set encoding=utf8

" Use Unix as the standard file type
set ffs=unix,dos,mac

" Set colors for tabbar
hi TabLineFill ctermbg=240
hi TabLine ctermbg=22
hi TabLineSel ctermbg=58

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Files, backups and undo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git etc anyway...
set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab

" Be smart when using tabs ;)
set smarttab

" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" Linebreak on 160 characters
set lbr
set tw=160

set ai "Auto indent
"set si "Smart indent
set cindent
set wrap "Wrap lines

map <leader>tn :tabnew<CR>
map <leader>tc :tabclose<CR>
map <leader>1 1gt
map <leader>2 2gt
map <leader>3 3gt
map <leader>4 4gt
map <leader>5 5gt
map <leader>6 6gt
map <leader>7 7gt
map <leader>8 8gt
map <leader>9 9gt
map <leader>0 10gt

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Visual mode pressing * or # searches for the current selection
" Super useful! From an idea by Michael Naumann
vnoremap <silent> * :call VisualSelection('f', '')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :call VisualSelection('b', '')<CR>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Moving around, tabs, windows and buffers
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Treat long lines as break lines (useful when moving around in them)
map j gj
map k gk


" Smart way to move between windows (deactivated as I use those shortcuts in tmux)
"map <C-j> <C-W>j
"map <C-k> <C-W>k
"map <C-h> <C-W>h
"map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Specify the behavior when switching between buffers 
try
  set switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
  set stal=2
catch
endtry

" Return to last edit position when opening files (You want this!)
autocmd BufReadPost *
     \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
     \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
     \ endif
" Remember info about open buffers on close
set viminfo^=%


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Status line
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Always show the status line
set laststatus=2


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Editing mappings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Delete trailing white space on save, useful for Python and CoffeeScript ;)
func! DeleteTrailingWS()
  exe "normal mz"
  %s/\s\+$//ge
  exe "normal `z"
endfunc
autocmd BufWrite *.py :call DeleteTrailingWS()


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Spell checking
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Pressing ,ss will toggle and untoggle spell checking
map <leader>ss :setlocal spell!<cr>

" Shortcuts using <leader>
map <leader>sn ]s
map <leader>sp [s
map <leader>sa zg
map <leader>s? z=


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Misc
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Quickly open a buffer for scribble
map <leader>bu :e ~/Downloads/vim-buffer<cr>
noremap <leader>ch :!evince ~/Pictures/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif &<cr><cr>
map <leader>to :tabnew ~/notes/todo<cr>
map <leader>pr :!evince 201*.pdf<cr>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Turn persistent undo on 
"    means that you can undo even when you close a buffer/VIM
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
try
    set undodir=~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir
    set undofile
catch
endtry


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Programming
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
noremap <leader>tl :TlistToggle<cr>:wincmd j<cr>:wincmd l<cr> 
noremap <leader>al :A<cr>

""" Path (command) to ctags
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = "ctags"
"let Tlist_WinWidth = 50

""" This command builds (updates) the ctags file for the SusyNt project, it can be enhanced (or split) later to account for other projects
map <leader>tu :!ctags -R --sort=1 --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ --exclude=.svn -f ~/.vim/ctags/SusyNt ~/SusyNt/SusyNtuple/Root/ ~/SusyNt/SusyNtuple/SusyNtuple/<cr><cr>
set tags=~/.vim/ctags/SusyNt

""" Taglist should be on the right to not interfere with NERDTree
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1

""" Define paths for alternate to look for its partner files (sfr means the path is relative)
let g:alternateSearchPath = 'sfr:.,sfr:../source,sfr:../src,sfr:../include,sfr:../Root,sfr:../inc,sfr:../HistFitterTree,sfr:../MultiLep,sfr:../SusyNtuple'

""" If there is no partner file, do nothing
let g:alternateNoDefaultAlternate = 1 

""" Taglist gets updated when saving
autocmd BufWritePost * :TlistUpdate

set makeprg=./vim-make
""" make and jump to warning/error if any
map <leader>m :make<cr>
""" make without jump to warning/error
map <leader>n :make!<cr>



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Sessions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! RestoreSession()
    if argc() == 0 "vim called without arguments
        execute 'source .Session.vim'
   end
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call RestoreSession()
autocmd VimLeave * :mksession! .Session.vim

" Store foldings
au BufWinLeave ?* mkview
au BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview

"From http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Custom-tabline-Non-gui-vim-td1190544.html
"if exists("+guioptions") 
"        set go-=a go-=e go+=tc 
"        " remove a  no autoselect to * register 
"        " remove e  always use text-style tabs 
"        " add    t  include tearoff menu items if possible 
"        " add    c  avoid popup dialogs for small choices 
"endif 

" define our text-style tabline 
" this is adapted (with some enhancements) from the example 
" at :help setting-tabline 
if exists("+showtabline") 
     function MyTabLine() 
         let s = '' 
         let t = tabpagenr() 
         let i = 1 
         while i <= tabpagenr('$') 
             let buflist = tabpagebuflist(i) 
             let winnr = tabpagewinnr(i) 
             let s .= '%' . i . 'T' 
             let s .= (i == t ? '%1*' : '%2*') 
             let s .= ' ' 
             let s .= i . ':' 
"             let s .= winnr . '/' . tabpagewinnr(i,'$') 
             let s .= ' %*' 
             let s .= (i == t ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#') 
             let file = bufname(buflist[winnr - 1]) 
             let file = fnamemodify(file, ':p:t') 
             if file == '' 
                 let file = '[No Name]' 
             endif 
             "let s .= file 
             let s .= (getbufvar(buflist[winnr - 1], "&mod")?'+ ':'')
             let s .= file
             let s .= (getbufvar(buflist[winnr - 1], "&mod")?' +':'')
             let i = i + 1
         endwhile
         let s .= '%T%#TabLineFill#%=' 
         let s .= (tabpagenr('$') > 1 ? '%999XX' : 'X') 
         return s 
     endfunction 
     set stal=2 
     set tabline=%!MyTabLine() 
"   map     <F10>    :tabnext<CR> 
"   map!    <F10>    <C-O>:tabnext<CR> 
"   map     <S-F10>  :tabprev<CR> 
"   map!    <S-F10>  <C-O>:tabprev<CR> 
endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.vimrc configuration for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523482/vimrc-configuration-for-python)

Comment: Can you please outline how your link should help me solving the problem?

Comment: Please do file a bug report for this. That way it can be fixed for everybody. Maintainer's address is at `:e $VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim`.

Comment: I'm using a plugin called [vim-python-pep8-indent](https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent) besides many others. In my environment, the code is indented as what you want. I am not 100% sure this plugin is the silver bullet, but give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a bug in the `indent/python.vim` file included with the release of Vim.

To check it, copy the file from `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.py` into your home vim directory (for example `$HOME/.vim/indent/python.py`) and look for the following paragraph (near the end of the file):

```
    " Unless the previous line was a one-liner
    if getline(plnumstart) =~ '^\s*\(for\|if\|try\)\>'
      return plindent
    endif
```

Change the condition to check for the keyword `elif` also:

```
    " Unless the previous line was a one-liner
    if getline(plnumstart) =~ '^\s*\(for\|if\|elif\|try\)\>'
      return plindent
    endif
```

Restart Vim and done!

Answer (score 2):

Vim is doing this because your code is not idiomatic and so it makes otherwise correct assumptions. The issue is with placing `pass` (or any other expression) on the same line. If you were to place them on new lines, this would not happen. In fact, vim is probably expecting (or implicitly trying to encourage) [PEP-008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out) which is the style guide for Python. The section I linked there (towards the end) talks exactly of the issue you're having, but not how to make vim bend to your will.

I'll assume that you don't care about writing idiomatic Python though, and answer your question:

In the directory vim's non-executable files are installed, you will find a directory called `indent` inside of which you will find a file called `python.vim`.

On [line 168](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/indent/python.vim#168), you'll see that by default it automatically dedents the line for you. It only does not do that if the previous line was a "one-liner" starting with an `if`, `for`, or `try` statement.

You can make your own, or you can submit a fix to vim but there is no setting for you to use in the interim. A "fix" would be to copy the file and apply your changes and then tell vim to use that instead.