# How to SIMPLY configure VIM for Python?

Tags: python, vim

Note: A previous question was closed because it needed to be more "focused", so I deleted the old one and modified the question so it only focus on VIM for Python.

I want to start using VIM but I´m having a hard time configuring it.

First, I did `:syntax on` to add some color to the syntax. Then, I wanted to change the version of Python that VIM is "verifying" as default (version 2+) to the recent version (3+) and did (something I found online) `:let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python3'`. After I did this, the `:syntax on` stopped working (no more syntax highlighting) and VIM still didn´t support python3. What I mean is that if I write in Python3 I get error because it doesn't recognize version 3+

I´m using VIM (version 8+) from Terminal on Mac High Sierra.

Question:

1. How can I configure VIM to work with Python ? - to work with recent version of Python(3+), have syntax highlight ON and have a "file tree".

Please, answer as simply as possible so anyone who is new to VIM can understand.  **I searched a lot and the answers I found were old and confusing to understand for someone who is new to VIM and wants to start with it.**

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but you seem to have confused your backtick key (\`) with the apostrophe ('). It's "doesn't", not "doesn`t".

Comment: What is the problem if you **only** use `:syntax on`? That would be "simple". Vim usually does not care about Python 2 or 3. It's a text editor, not a Python interpreter.

Comment: The problem, like I tried to explain, `:syntax on` stopped working

Comment: If you use `:syntax on`, `:syntax on` stops working? You wrote that it stopped working after you did *something else*. But what if you don't do anything else, but start with a vanilla Vim without any plugins or fancy stuff and use *just* `:syntax on` and open a Python file?

Comment: I did `:let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python3'` (something I found online) to try to change python default version to 3+ (which didn´t work). After I did that the syntax is no longer highlighting, even if I do `:syntax on`

Comment: Yes. What if you **don't** use `:let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python3'`?

Comment: Yesterday it wasn´t working, now it seems to be working. Don´t know what I did... Still have the problem with the default version. How can I change the default version? I found many articles but all of them seem to have different ways of changing it. I want to know what´s the right way of doing it...

Comment: Where do you want to change the default version of what? What is the "problem with the default version"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 VIM is not recognizing the syntax of python 3+. I believe cause I have python 2.7 as default, even tho I have python 3+ installed.  It's something I should configure on VIM or something external to VIM?

Comment: What do you mean by it is "not recognizing the syntax of Python 3"? What happens? Is it recognizing the syntax of Python 2?

Comment: What Vim does is not related to which Python version you have installed, of if you have Python installed at all. You can edit Python files with Vim, with syntax highlighting, without having Python installed.

Comment: @mkrieger1 check the chat If you can

Comment: Try one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523482/vimrc-configuration-for-python), some have very simple settings for `.vimrc`.

Comment: @progmatico Thanks! Sorry for my ignorance, when I configure a .vimrc it will work for every project? Even If I create a new project in different folder and use a different language?

Comment: The answer is yes, vim is a text editor with its own configuration that is loaded every time you start it. Nothing to do with you projects. But be sure to put (or edit) the`.vimrc` in the right place. Inside vim, in command mode do `: he vimrc` (means help vimrc, or any other keyword you like) and read.

Comment: You can search answers and post questions about vim in StackOverflow too, and tag them only with vim tag. Vim has  a tutorial in the internal help, and there are some resources to learn about it in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

For the file tree, I would suggest the NerdTree plugin.

As for your syntax checker not working, I suggest you first create a Python 3 virtual environment via Pipenv, then open your vim within that virtual environment. That might solve your problem. You should always be using a virtual environment in any case if you are writing Python code.

Comment: Vim should be working fine without using a Python virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into NerdTree. By the way, why should people always use virtual environment if code in Python?

Comment: @DGF, you are not really required, except when you want to isolate the Python version and the third-party library dependencies to use from project to project. This means *almost always* :), except maybe when you are at the very beginning of your Python experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using coc.nvim. It is not entirely simple, but it is the simplest I know after trying a few alternatives.

Here is a relatively simple guide:

First install [vim-plug](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vim%20plug&t=osx&kp=1): In your terminal, enter

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Then install [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim):
This plugin requires nodejs,

```
curl -sL install-node.now.sh/lts | bash
```

Now put this code in your `~/.vimrc`

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')    
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
call plug#end()
```

Restart Vim, and type `:PlugInstall` and press enter. This will install the plugin for you.

Copy the default [example vim configuration](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim#example-vim-configuration) to the end of your `~/.vimrc` (or anywhere after the `plug#end()`).

Inside vim, issue the command `:CocInstall coc-python`. This will install [coc-python](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python), which is their python support.

Inside vim, issue the command `:CocConfig`. This will open up a file `coc-settings.json`. Put in the following code in the file to use MS's Python language server.

```
{
    "python.jediEnabled": false
}
```

Note that you can use `jedi` as well. I'm opting for MS because it's simpler to setup.

Restart vim and open a `.py` file. It will take a moment to install MS Python language server. After that, you should get syntax analysis and code completion.

To select an interpreter (python3), do `:CocCommand`, and you should see an option to set the interpreter. For virtual environments to show up, you can activate the virtual env in the command line before starting vim.